# Xcode, Swift - Adding Index List to Array of Custom Cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

The code that I am working with at the moment is the following:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ShopViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var button_filter: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar_shop: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var view_navigator: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView_shop: UITableView!
    var ShopCells: [ShopCell] = []
    var databaseRef: DatabaseReference!
    var storageRef: StorageReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        self.storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()
        createArray() { shopCells in
            for item in shopCells {
                self.ShopCells.append(item)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView_shop.reloadData()
            }
        }
        self.navigationItem.title = "Shop"
        self.tableView_shop.delegate = self
        self.tableView_shop.dataSource = self
        self.searchBar_shop.delegate = self
        self.searchBar_shop.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#1ABC9C")
        self.view_navigator.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#1ABC9C")
        self.tableView_shop.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
        self.searchBar_shop.isTranslucent = false
        self.searchBar_shop.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ShopViewController.viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func viewTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar_shop.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func createArray(completion: @escaping ([ShopCell]) -> () ) {
        var tempShopCells: [ShopCell] = []
        let rootRef = Database.database().reference()

        let query = rootRef.child("tobaccos").queryOrdered(byChild: "name")
        query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
            for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let value = child.value as? [String: Any];
                let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? "";
                let brand = value?["brand"] as? String ?? "";
                let iD = value?["iD"] as? String ?? "";

                dispatchGroup.enter()
                let imageReference = Storage.storage().reference().child("tobaccoPictures").child("\(iD).jpg")
                imageReference.getData(maxSize: (1 * 1024 * 1024)) { (data, error) in
                    if let _error = error{
                        print(_error)
                    } else {
                        if let _data  = data {
                            let image: UIImage! = UIImage(data: _data)
                            tempShopCells.append(ShopCell(productName: name, brandName: brand, productImage: image, iD: iD))
                        }
                    }
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }
            }
            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
                completion(tempShopCells)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ShopViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.ShopCells.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let shopCell = ShopCells[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView_shop.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ShopCell") as! ShopTableViewCell
        cell.setShopCell(shopCell: shopCell)
        return cell
    }

}
```

ShopCell.swift:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ShopCell {
    var productName: String
    var brandName: String
    var productImage: UIImage
    var iD: String

    init(productName: String, brandName: String, productImage: UIImage, iD: String) {
        self.productName = productName
        self.brandName = brandName
        self.productImage = productImage
        self.iD = iD
    }
}
```

ShopTableViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class ShopTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var view_background: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view_verticalLine: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView_get: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView_productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label_productName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label_brandName: UILabel!

    func setShopCell(shopCell: ShopCell) {
        self.label_productName.text = shopCell.productName
        self.label_brandName.text = shopCell.brandName
        self.imageView_productImage.image = shopCell.productImage
        self.view_verticalLine.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#1ABC9C")
        self.imageView_get.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        self.view_background.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.view_background.layer.shadowRadius = 3
        self.view_background.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    }
}
```

What the output looks like for now:

[image]

I would like to add an Index List (this alphabetic thing) to the right side of the View based on the "name" displayed in my cells. Now, I have found some solutions for sections but not when working with custom cells in an array like I do. Basically I also don't want to show these letters (looking like a separator) above a bunch of cells. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Please add the custom cell code.

Comment: @George Edited my question

Comment: @George You have an idea?

Comment: I am not sure i understood you question? What is index list?

Comment: @George It's that little alphabetical list at the right side e.g. also in the contacts app of iOS with which you can simply jump to contacs that begin with the selected letter...